# Anyone know what style outdoor faucet valve stem this is?

Tags: plumbing

Trying to replace an outdoor faucet valve stem and handle, but can't find the manufacturer and model. TIA.[image: Faucet valve stem and handle]

Comment: There's a good chance you could take that stem to a good hardware store and find a new handle to fit. And they would certainly have rubber bib washers to fit the other end.

Answer (score 4):

This valve stem is from a standard sillcock similar to the one shown below from Lowe's. I doubt you'll find an exact replacement, maybe from a plumbing supply store. These units are usually just replaced. Go behind the wall from the other side and look for the other end. Depending on your plumbing, it should just unscrew and pull it out from the outside. Buy one the same size and reinstall it according to any directions.

[image]

Comment: Replacing a "frost-free" hose bib is frequently a large project, involving destruction of finished inside wall/ceiling surfaces. Not to mention the waste of time and materials. They are also often soldered in place, rather than screwed. It is always better to replace only defective components of the faucet, if at all possible.

Comment: @kreemoweet   The OP stated he's trying to replace it, not repair it. The dozen or so I've done went as stated in my answer.  Try writing your own answer and don't be so fast to DV.

Comment: Granted, sill cocks have gotten ridiculously expensive of late (as has everything), @kreemoweet, but replacement is often quite simple, too.